# How to forward calls to specified phone numbers based on the incoming extension number with android?

Tags: android

This question sounds a bit odd, and it is maybe impossible, but I really need to do something like this, and I need a cheap solution.

What I would like to do is to use and Android phone to forward incoming calls to specified numbers based on the extension number. Is it possible virtually? I do not have real extensions, just one Android device with only one phone number, so that is why I am thinking about extension numbers, I think this is the only way to identify the target number with a cellphone.

Sample:

```
My number: 00491234567
When user calls 00491234567-01 it will ring at 00490987654
When user calls 00491234567-02 it will ring at 00490456789
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for needs to be provided by the telephone switching network, not the phone itself.

When someone dials `00491234567-01` on their phone, the number will either be rejected as being malformed, or the `-01` addition will be ignored and not send via the call control protocols.

Comment: and what if the caller enters the 01 after calling?

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work.  Would the phone answer the call and then wait for the caller to enter the "extension"?  I haven't tried it, but from what I read, it is not necessarily possible for an app to get access to the audio input from a caller.  Even if it could do so, and it could decode the extension, then what?  Would it have to setup a 3-way call by calling the "actual" number for the destination?  This type of capability usually exists in telephony equipment with access to call-control signalling features on the network.  Again, I'm not sure how you could do it from a handeset.